# download a file from server to mobile device in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am able to download a file from sever in desktop .
But not able to download a file in mobile device.

Like to download a file in mobile device in js code

Comment: 1) What are you wanting help with how to do? It's not clear from your question.
2) What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that you've written so far on this problem?
3) Mobile devices may sandbox where they let you download files to - iPhones for example will let you open a file if it can find something that can handle it, but won't just let you generically download a file and store it anywhere, I think. Is this a problem for what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript is a client-side scripting language**

You're going to have to use node.js. JavaScript is a client-side scripting language and you can make requests through JavaScript, but you can't perform server-side actions from inside a certain object/environment with JavaScript.